# Is there a moderator FAQ or documentation available for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, moderation, documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq)

I was just made a moderator on one of the Stack Exchange sites outside of the main trilogy and am feeling my way around the dark a bit.

For example, it seems that since I got moderator privileges, when I click on a close link, the system actually closes the question immediately instead of just adding a vote to close it.

Is there a FAQ or documentation available to help new moderators?

Comment: Have you tried asking on Meta StackExchange?

Comment: Jon's suggestion says enough, it's a good question, just not in the right place

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'll re-post over there.

Comment: It looks like this question was asked in the SE 1.0 era, but there is a FAQ for new (and not-so-new) mods now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq. Maybe we should reopen this and close it as a dupe of that?

Comment: @PopularDemand: *Nudge*, now we can ;)