# Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities, moderator-faq

As per the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), this FAQ will serve the following purposes:

- To be *the* canonical reference for moderators across the Stack Exchange sites for things that are *beyond question* (typically, "*how*" questions)
- For situations that a moderator will face, provide information to help understand the nuances of that situation, so that the moderator can make best possible decision that is in the interest of their Stack Exchange site and Stack Exchange in general (typically, "*when*" questions)
- To bring new moderators on sites (pro tempore or elected) up to speed quicker.

### Essential Reading

- [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)
- [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator Community Blog](http://stackmod.blog/)
- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119111/140951)

### Tools

- [What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4565)
- [How do I contact a user privately, as a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119098/how-do-i-contact-a-user-privately-as-a-moderator)
- [How can I contact Stack Exchange staff about a user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259239)
- [How can I find posts with excessive numbers of comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118802/how-can-i-find-posts-with-excessive-numbers-of-comments)
- [Why does one of the moderator's history stats show up red?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96442/why-does-one-of-the-moderators-history-stats-show-up-red)
- [Reporting bugs in moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115971/reporting-bugs-in-moderator-tools)
- [How can I search for deleted posts as a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134046/how-can-i-search-for-deleted-posts-as-a-moderator)
- [When will CMs or moderators remove the [featured] tag from actively featured meta questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343527/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-the-featured-tag)

### Post content

- [How does the “rude or abusive” flag work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22174)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)
- [What are our policies regarding self-harm and suicide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355421/what-are-our-policies-regarding-self-harm-and-suicide)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474)
- [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668)
- [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)
- [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117)

### Voting to Close

- [As a mod when should I vote to close content that is not flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124097)

### Comment flags

- [How do I handle off-topic comments (as a moderator)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119078/140951)

### Profile content

- [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/140951)
- [Why is the f word still allowed in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31197/140951)

### Abuse

- [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)
- [Code of Conduct Reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/harassment)

### Post notices

- [What does the "Current event" post notice mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean)

### Chat

- [What commands can be used with the 'Stack' chatbot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115015)
- [Moderating Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119117/116207)

### People

- [Current list of moderators on all of the Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)
- [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338)

### Miscellaneous

- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189)
- [Which actions using the 10k-moderator-tools do really help the diamond moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96473/which-actions-using-the-10k-moderator-tools-do-really-help-the-diamond-moderator)

Comment: It seems like quite a few links in this post have changed or become out of date (e.g. the linked post is only specific to a particular site, or has been closed as a duplicate of a different canonical post).