# As a moderator, what should I do to merge users?

Tags: discussion, moderation, merge-accounts

Sometimes an unregistered user lost their cookies and register with same email, then we get flags like... *I can't comment to my posts!!!*

In this case, what should I do as moderator?

- Encourage them to [request account merging from /contact](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)
- Use ["contact community team" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259239/286934)
- Ping CM in per site mods room (or Teachers' Lounge)

However, those methods may take a while. How do I handle if they want to add comment to their posts while merging? I got them to post it as an answer and I converted it to comment, but repeating this makes them blocked from posting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Encourage them to request account merging via the contact link (and leave a helpful comment explaining that they may have ended up with multiple accounts).

Because of a number of risks and quirks in account merging tools, handling these cases is beyond the scope of the moderation team. Since merges, however, deal with personally-identifying information, they need to be requested by the user rather than the moderator.