# How can I search for deleted posts as a moderator?

Tags: support, search, deleted-questions, moderator-tools

I was looking for [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/552/vertical-salt-bridge), so I searched ["salt bridge"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22salt%20bridge%22). The search results were empty, though I can see the post itself (I have a ♦ on the site).

`/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today` and `/admin/recently-self-deleted` are still caching (22 minutes, but still caching), so the question has effectively disappeared.

Anyway, the `/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today` and `/admin/recently-self-deleted` aren't searchable.

Can't 10k/♦ users get the option(not enabled by default) to view deleted questions via search?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Moderators have access to a search operator that will enable searching of deleted questions and answers.

- `deleted:0` returns no deleted posts (default)
- `deleted:1` returns only deleted posts
- `deleted:all` returns any post matching the rest of the query, deleted or otherwise.

Example: [`"salt bridge" deleted:1`](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22salt+bridge%22+deleted%3A1) should produce a result, provided you have moderator rights on Chemistry.SE.

[Users with the “moderator tools” privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users) (10k rep on graduated sites, 2k on beta sites) can also now use these operators, but this only returns their own deleted posts, not other users'.

Comment: Hmm, why did I never notice that? I have all the other search operators memorized... :/

Comment: One of those things that should be in a list somewhere...I had to tell @Won't about this a while ago

Comment: Linked to it in [the mod faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq), @Ben.