# Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, deleted-posts

I just tried to find a recent answer I wrote (or comment, can't remember), but I couldn't. I assume the question was deleted. Can the `deleted:1` [operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134047/167534) be enabled to 10k users? We can see deleted posts, so why can't we at least target them in search?

I understand that allowing us to search for all deleted posts from someone else can be problematic. Quoting Yannis Rizos' comments:

> if `deleted:1` becomes available to 10K+ users there should be a restriction on coupling it with a user id (except perhaps when you are searching for your own deleted posts).

So, `user:<userID> deleted:1` would be disallowed (except for your own user id), but something like `[tag] deleted:1` would be allowed.

Comment: See also [Can we have an isdeleted:1 search option/operator?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator), although that wasn't asking for a restriction to 10k users, which I think makes sense.

Comment: Interesting [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41145/167534) by Adam Davis there. I understand why we don't have deleted posts on our profile listings, but maybe the 10k restriction I suggest is still an acceptable compromise.

Comment: @bfavaretto `user:<userID> deleted:1` is essentially the same thing as seeing deleted posts on a user's profile, if `deleted:1` becomes available to 10K+ users there should be a restriction on coupling it with a user id (except perhaps when you are searching for your own deleted posts).

Comment: @YannisRizos Fair enough, I'd be happy to be able to search my own posts only.

Comment: Hm, not what I meant, I don't have a problem with 10K users searching for deleted posts (I've upvoted this), but there should be a restriction for searching for a specific user's deleted posts. But I don't see why there would be a problem for searches like for example `[tag] deleted:1`.

Comment: @YannisRizos Nice idea! May I incorporate that into the feature-request?

Comment: By all means, if you think it will help the feature.

Comment: Personally I'd be in favor for searching for your own deleted posts as 10k.  Searching for other deleted posts not necessarily yours (such as `[tag] deleted:1`) ought to be 20k.

Comment: This has been done now, and guess what? They forgot the "there should be a restriction on coupling it with a user id" part and any 10k user can see any other user's deleted posts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are you sure? It seems to be fixed, then. E.g., this [search for Jon Skeet's deleted content](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+deleted%3A1) actually returns my own deleted posts.

Comment: @bfavaretto yeah it was a bug that was fixed soon after reported here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We recently enabled searching for own deleted content for 10k users as a result of [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253674/1438). Note that you can still see your own deleted content on your profile [for 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/1438). This privilege enhancement gives you access to older content that you own.

[Jeff's concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#comment222981_53297) with allowing people to see their own deleted content was that "it would lead to unbelievable amounts of whining." As we've relaxed the restrictions, that hasn't happened. Jeff was right to be worried, but as it turns out he was wrong about how people would respond. That's a real encouragement.

Looking at the date of the original question, I see that this feature was over three years in gestation. Late is better than never, I suppose.

Comment: Isn't 10k a little too restrictive? On most sites 5k rep signifies a sufficiently high level of contribution that one should be allowed this privilege.

Comment: Why 10k, eh? Why can't I see the list of my deleted posts before 10k?

Comment: Most likely because 10k is the threshold for seeing deleted posts on full sites in the first place.

Comment: Deleted posts of others, sure, but still why not your own (assuming it wasn't deleted as spam, etc)

Comment: @Drew For some reason the StackOverflow team doesn't want *any* deleted posts to be viewable by anyone until they have reached that threshold. I don't know the reason; personally I disagree and think users should *always* be able to see their own deleted posts regardless of reputation.

Comment: The one exception is your own deleted posts are visible on your activity page for three months.

Comment: @TylerH: It's actually possible to view your own older posts _if_ you remember (or can discover) the URL/PostId. We've been slowly opening up the gates (for instance, putting [metadata of deleted posts on SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/1438)) and watching for problems.

Comment: That is why it's important to drag and drop those urls into a followup folder or bookmark concept.

Comment: @FatherChristmas Right, I was referring to "searching" for your deleted posts when I said "see their own deleted posts", sorry. You can always see your own *if you know the URL*.

Comment: But I agree with not *easily* being able to see them in retrospect for under 10k. One of the privileges of 10K is seeing deleted posts and the trust that you will not stir up stink seen in them

Answer (score 6):

So to write this as a simple answer, for 10K users to see all their deleted content, just write `deleted:1` in the search bar.

[image]

Comment: You actually don't need to search for your user ID, according to [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) `deleted:1` will return all your deleted posts.

Comment: @Laurel, Great! Even better.

Comment: Even if you did have to include the user, you can use `user:me` for yourself, no need for the ID