# How can I check which answer of mine was deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers

One of my answers has been deleted, but I'm not able to find which one it is and why. 
Is there any way to find to which answer it was, and why it got deleted from my SO account?

I had 187 answers but now it's 186.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1890488/user19340357

I can't see any rep change in the rep history either.

Comment: For you last sentence: In reputation tab click on *show removed posts*. It will show you removed posts where your reputation is affected.

Comment: i checked that , it shows nothing.

Comment: @hims056 that only works if the answer had votes

Comment: If you had comments for that answer it might still exist in your "inbox" tab on your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2129276/user19340357).

Comment: but how will i know that which answer it was  , there are many comments from many answers

Comment: @jmfsg - Yeh thats why I added at last : *where your reputation is affected*. :)

Comment: 10ks and the owners used to be able to see deleted answers in the profile, but it appears that has now been restricted to mods.

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ yes its seems .. can  not see deleted post ..

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ If you mean in the user profile of a user, that is only possible for moderators, but it has been so for a while now. Other users can see a deleted answer if they flagged it, and they are 10K users, or if they are given a link to the answer (and they are 10K users).

Comment: @Catija: Doesn't seem to be answerable with the instructions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question which you had answered was deleted 10 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515695/js-game-assistance

And since the SE engine likes to convert this answer to a comment when posting it, here's the content of your deleted answer:

> You need to use some server side language like php so that when the user play for the first time then you mark that in the database and you need to check that before running the game.
>
> You can store the ip information if you don't have any other details to store
>
> you can also use cookies to store the user information. But if the user chnage the browser or delete them then you can't do anything

Since that answer had zero votes there is indeed no way to find that on your own - even I had to go through your deleted answers and check which one was deleted today.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your deleted posts by [searching `deleted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes) on the site in question.

Note this shows only your own deleted posts.

Comment: this feature is currently available only for 10K users, [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562/165773)