Add users' deleted questions in search results
It's not a duplicate of Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users because I'm not only asking for the less than 1% of users with >10k rep who have the 'Access to Moderator Tools' privilege.


Feature request: when any user makes a search, add that user's deleted questions amongst the search results.
Motivation: when making a search for a past question of mine, I sometimes can't recall if my question got deleted.


If you don't know if was deleted, you can just make 2 searches, one with deleted:1 and 1 without. Not that hard for a niche case.

This already exists as the deleted:yes, deleted:no, and deleted:any options for search. It is available to users with the "access to moderator tools" privilege. I don't recall if it was extended to all users when SE changed the profile pages to show all of the user's deleted questions and answers.

@Makyen That's already done...presumably Franck wants something else...

@Makyen thanks, I was unaware of deleted:all. Wish that was default though, but I guess that's a matter of personal preference.

@Starship I had missed deleted:all. I only knew about deleted:0 and deleted:1.

@Makyen deleted:any isn't mentioned in the target you linked.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, Yes, but deleted:all is mentioned in the basic search help. If you insist that it be mention in the duplicate, it's trivial to add it. Regardless, this [tag:feature-request] is asking for something that already explicitly exists and is documented in the basic help for the feature that's being asked about. The user clearly didn't bother to read even just the search help page. It was added to the search docs sometime between 2016-05-07 and 2020-10-25, based on archive.org captures. You're welcome to find a better duplicate, or close as "no repo".

@Makyen The search operator deleted:all only works if the user has earned the Access to Moderator Tools privilege. It therefore doesn't satisfy this feature request.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If you're looking for other duplicates, then I'd suggest looking in the time frame mentioned above, and around the time the time the ability for everyone to see their full deleted posts was added. IIRC, it was asked if this would be expanded to all users, and SE said "No".

@FranckDernoncourt No, your question doesn't say you want it expanded to all users. You just ask for it to exist. It does exist. We can alternately close this as "unclear"/"Needs details".

Note that expanding to < 10k has already been previously asked, with the response of "No". I don't recall if it was an actual question or just in comments.

@Makyen "Feature request: when user A makes a search, add user A's deleted questions amongst the search results." why would you assume I'm only asking for the 1% of users with >10k rep?

@Makyen "Note that expanding to < 10k has already been previously asked, with the response of "No". I don't recall if it was an actual question or just in comments" ok great, then that'd be a dupe if such a question exists.

@FranckDernoncourt Because you are asking explicitly for your own use. You have > 10k. Thus, what you're asking for exists. You even explicitly state that a solution exists for you in your answer here.

@Makyen I have > 10k rep on ~6% of SE sites. My answer states "Partial solution". What do you think partial means?

A bit more detailed look at archive.org, using SO instead of MSE, indicates the documentation for the deleted operator was added to the search documentation page sometime between 2019-01-13 and 2019-04-08.

@Makyen See this post for the announcement of the ability for users to view lists of their own deleted posts: it says We're also going to keep the deleted:1 search function as a high-rep user perk. Also, note that while the "motivation" talks about the user themselves, the "feature request" asks for it for "user A", i.e., everyone, and makes no mention of the privilege requirement.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That's not how questions are intended to work. Reasonably writing a [tag:feature-request] question takes into context what currently exists and asks for something to be implemented that doesn't exist. This question doesn't do that, despite the OP having had the opportunity to edit once they learned of their mistaken understanding about the existence of the feature (i.e., that it does exist). As this question is currently written, it's a duplicate of those questions, as those questions fully answer this question as it currently exists.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That doesn't mean this question couldn't be [edit]ed to be an actual [tag:feature-request] for a feature that doesn't exist, but it would need to be rewritten to take into account the context A) that the feature does already exist, and B) that SE has already explicitly said "no" to having this as a feature for everyone, and explicitly request reconsideration of the decision to keep this feature as a > 10k privilege.

@Makyen "SE has already explicitly said "no" to having this as a feature for everyone" where?

@Starship It's not a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060/178179 because I'm not only asking for the less than 1% of users with >10k rep.

@FranckDernoncourt Oooh...then its a dupe of something else...lemme go find that

@FranckDernoncourt Behold....the dupe

@Starship thank you, regrettably the OP closed the feature request by stating "this post can be considered both [tag:status-completed] and [tag:status-declined]".

Now it is 100% duplicate, added exact dupe target.

Partial solution: The search operator deleted:all will add the user's own deleted questions amongst the search results, however this only works if the user has earned the Access to Moderator Tools privilege. IMHO it'd be preferable to not require having earned the Access to Moderator Tools privilege in that case, since deleted questions are already available to the user under https://[SE_site].stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/[user_ID].
