# Can deleted posts be queried on data explorer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, data-explorer, deleted-answers

For various reasons, I would like to search though posts *including deleted ones*, however it seems that deleted posts are not exported.

If there a way to query them?

If not, why aren't deleted posts exported? What's the big deal? The percentage of posts that are deleted is not that big - I would expect that exporting them too wouldn't make a big impact on data explorer.

Comment: Except that people can make use of that to allow everyone to see deleted posts (I know I will). You as a moderator [should be able to search delete posts in the search box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134046/how-can-i-search-for-deleted-posts-as-a-moderator).

Comment: @Antony I was hoping there would be some DE kung fu that would let me do it. I want to search for spam, but I want to see how effective it *would have been* as well as finding more that should have been deleted, so I would like the query to return deleted posts too. Not a show stopper, but it would be nice.